# Какие есть циркумфиксы?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Где в этих словах циркумфиксы и каково их значение: *подстаканник, зарубежье*? Какие циркумфиксы еще есть в русском языке?

Answer (score 1):

**Циркумфикс** {лат. circumfixus – укрепленный кругом} – лингв. разновидность аффикса, состоящая **из двух частей** – префикса и постфикса, несущих одно значение.

Если считать, что циркумфикс – это формант, **состоящий из приставки и суффикса**, то таких примеров в русском языке достаточно, то есть это префиксально-суффиксальный способ образования слов.  Стакан – подстаканник, циркумфикс ПОД...НИК.  А вот зарубежье может не подойти, так как есть слово "зарубеж" (хотя оно относится к разговорному стилю).

Если считать, что речь идет именно о **постфиксе**, то у нас только один постфикс СЯ. Например, расшумелся – здесь циркумфикс РАС...СЯ.

[ЦИРКУМФИКСЫ В РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ КАК ПОКАЗАТЕЛИ АКТАНТНОЙ ДЕРИВАЦИИ.pdf | hse.ru](https://www.hse.ru/pubs/share/direct/document/66515033)